# How to create a list of Networks in R based on Time Series Data

Tags: r, time-series, network-analysis

I'm attempting to look at networks of individuals and site visits over a time series.  Essentially, the end result I'd like to achieve is similar to the `"beaches"` dataset found in package `"dnr"`.  I have a larger dataset dput for a subset of which is shown at the bottom.

Basically I would like to `split()` this table by both `Species` and `Week` and then create an incidence matrix with rows of distinct values from `TagID` and columns based on distinct values in `SiteVisits`. Then i use package `igraph` and `graph_from_incidence_matrix` to create a unique network for each species for each week.

I started with an attempt to split the main table by species and then create new tables for each species for each week:

```
DFsplit <- split(DF, DF$Species)
DFsplit_cf <- split(DFsplit$Catfish, DFsplit$Catfish$Week)
```

this worked fine, but when I attempted to write a loop to build a network using this dataframe

```
network_builder <- function(data) {
  for(i in 1: length(data)) {
    adjacency <- xtabs(~ data[[i]][,3] + data[[i]][,4])
    network[i] <- graph_from_incidence_matrix(adjacency)
  }
}

network_builder(DFsplit_stb)
```

I received

```
 Error in model.frame.default(formula = ~data[[i]][, 3] + data[[i]][, 4]) : 
  invalid type (list) for variable 'data[[i]][, 3]'
```

I'm guessing there's a way to get around this error, but nothing I've tried is working. Also, if there is a cleaner way to do this, I'm all ears.

dput:

```
structure(list(Species = c("Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Largemouth Bass", "Largemouth Bass", "Largemouth Bass", 
"Largemouth Bass", "Largemouth Bass", "Largemouth Bass", "Largemouth Bass", 
"Largemouth Bass", "Largemouth Bass", "Largemouth Bass", "Largemouth Bass", 
"Largemouth Bass", "Largemouth Bass", "Largemouth Bass", "Largemouth Bass", 
"Largemouth Bass", "Largemouth Bass", "Largemouth Bass", "Largemouth Bass", 
"Largemouth Bass", "Largemouth Bass", "Largemouth Bass", "Largemouth Bass", 
"Largemouth Bass", "Largemouth Bass", "Largemouth Bass", "Largemouth Bass", 
"Largemouth Bass", "Largemouth Bass", "Largemouth Bass", "Largemouth Bass", 
"Largemouth Bass", "Largemouth Bass", "Largemouth Bass", "Largemouth Bass", 
"Largemouth Bass", "Largemouth Bass", "Largemouth Bass", "Largemouth Bass", 
"Largemouth Bass", "Largemouth Bass", "Largemouth Bass", "Largemouth Bass", 
"Largemouth Bass", "Largemouth Bass", "Largemouth Bass", "Largemouth Bass", 
"Largemouth Bass", "Largemouth Bass", "Largemouth Bass", "Largemouth Bass", 
"Largemouth Bass", "Largemouth Bass", "Largemouth Bass", "Largemouth Bass", 
"Largemouth Bass", "Largemouth Bass", "Largemouth Bass", "Largemouth Bass", 
"Largemouth Bass", "Largemouth Bass", "Largemouth Bass", "Largemouth Bass", 
"Largemouth Bass", "Largemouth Bass", "Largemouth Bass", "Largemouth Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Largemouth Bass", "Largemouth Bass", 
"Largemouth Bass", "Largemouth Bass", "Largemouth Bass", "Largemouth Bass", 
"Largemouth Bass", "Largemouth Bass", "Largemouth Bass", "Largemouth Bass", 
"Largemouth Bass", "Largemouth Bass", "Largemouth Bass", "Largemouth Bass", 
"Largemouth Bass", "Largemouth Bass", "Largemouth Bass", "Largemouth Bass", 
"Largemouth Bass", "Largemouth Bass", "Largemouth Bass", "Largemouth Bass", 
"Largemouth Bass", "Largemouth Bass", "Largemouth Bass", "Largemouth Bass", 
"Largemouth Bass", "Largemouth Bass", "Largemouth Bass", "Largemouth Bass", 
"Largemouth Bass", "Largemouth Bass", "Largemouth Bass", "Largemouth Bass", 
"Largemouth Bass", "Largemouth Bass", "Largemouth Bass", "Largemouth Bass", 
"Largemouth Bass", "Largemouth Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Catfish", "Catfish", "Catfish", 
"Catfish", "Catfish", "Catfish", "Catfish", "Catfish", "Catfish", 
"Catfish", "Catfish", "Catfish", "Catfish", "Catfish", "Catfish", 
"Catfish", "Catfish", "Catfish", "Catfish", "Catfish", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Largemouth Bass", "Largemouth Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Largemouth Bass", 
"Largemouth Bass", "Largemouth Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass"), Week = c(74, 74, 75, 76, 77, 
77, 77, 77, 77, 77, 78, 78, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 80, 80, 
80, 80, 81, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 84, 84, 84, 84, 84, 85, 85, 85, 
85, 85, 86, 86, 86, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 92, 92, 93, 93, 
93, 93, 93, 94, 94, 94, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 96, 96, 96, 96, 96, 
96, 96, 96, 97, 97, 97, 97, 98, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 100, 101, 
101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 102, 103, 103, 103, 103, 103, 
104, 104, 104, 104, 105, 105, 105, 105, 106, 106, 106, 106, 107, 
107, 107, 107, 108, 109, 110, 54, 54, 55, 55, 55, 56, 56, 56, 
57, 57, 57, 58, 60, 60, 60, 61, 61, 68, 68, 68, 69, 70, 70, 71, 
72, 73, 74, 74, 75, 76, 76, 77, 78, 78, 79, 80, 80, 81, 84, 86, 
86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 90, 91, 91, 92, 92, 93, 93, 94, 97, 97, 98, 
98, 98, 100, 100, 100, 101, 101, 101, 103, 103, 103, 164, 165, 
165, 165, 165, 166, 166, 166, 167, 168, 168, 168, 57, 58, 58, 
59, 60, 61, 61, 61, 62, 62, 63, 63, 63, 66, 70, 71, 74, 75, 76, 
76, 76, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 84, 20, 6, 7, 8, 
8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 
14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 16, 16, 17, 17, 17, 204, 204, 204, 205, 205, 
206, 206, 206, 207, 207, 207, 208, 208, 208, 209, 209, 209, 210, 
216, 228, 233, 233, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237, 239, 239, 240, 241, 
241, 242, 242, 243, 244, 244, 244, 245, 245, 64, 64, 64, 65, 
66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 72, 73, 73, 73, 74, 75, 76, 76, 76, 
77, 77, 77, 78, 78, 78, 79, 79, 79, 79, 80, 80, 81, 81, 83, 83, 
83, 84, 84, 84, 85, 86, 86, 87, 94, 95, 97, 97, 97, 97, 98, 99, 
99, 99, 100, 102, 103, 103, 103, 105, 106, 107, 107, 107, 107, 
108, 108, 108, 108, 109, 109, 109, 110, 110, 110, 110, 111, 111, 
111, 111, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 
98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 102, 102, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 
159, 160, 161, 161, 161, 162, 162, 163, 163, 163, 164, 165, 166, 
49, 14, 14, 185, 47, 74, 74, 75, 75, 75, 76, 76, 76, 78, 78, 
78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 83, 84, 84, 85, 85, 3, 3, 146, 147, 148, 
149, 149, 149, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 109, 77, 78, 79, 
20, 20, 21, 21, 21, 22, 22, 22, 23, 23, 23, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 
27, 40, 40, 40, 40, 41, 41, 45, 45, 45, 50, 50, 50, 52, 52, 52, 
45, 45, 45, 46, 46, 46, 48, 48), TagID = c(5004.24, 5004.24, 
5004.24, 5004.24, 5004.24, 5004.24, 5004.24, 5004.24, 5004.24, 
5004.24, 5004.24, 5004.24, 5004.24, 5004.24, 5004.24, 5004.24, 
5004.24, 5004.24, 5004.24, 5004.24, 5004.24, 5004.24, 5004.24, 
5004.24, 5004.24, 5004.24, 5004.24, 5004.24, 5004.24, 5004.24, 
5004.24, 5004.24, 5004.24, 5004.24, 5004.24, 5004.24, 5004.24, 
5004.24, 5004.24, 5004.24, 5004.24, 5004.24, 5004.24, 5004.24, 
5004.24, 5004.24, 5004.24, 5004.24, 5004.24, 5004.24, 5004.24, 
5004.24, 5004.24, 5004.24, 5004.24, 5004.24, 5004.24, 5004.24, 
5004.24, 5004.24, 5004.24, 5004.24, 5004.24, 5004.24, 5004.24, 
5004.24, 5004.24, 5004.24, 5004.24, 5004.24, 5004.24, 5004.24, 
5004.24, 5004.24, 5004.24, 5004.24, 5004.24, 5004.24, 5004.24, 
5004.24, 5004.24, 5004.24, 5004.24, 5004.24, 5004.24, 5004.24, 
5004.24, 5004.24, 5004.24, 5004.24, 5004.24, 5004.24, 5004.24, 
5004.24, 5004.24, 5004.24, 5004.24, 5004.24, 5004.24, 5004.24, 
5004.24, 5004.24, 5004.24, 5004.24, 5004.24, 5004.24, 5004.24, 
5004.24, 5004.24, 5004.24, 5004.24, 5004.24, 5004.24, 5004.24, 
5004.24, 5004.24, 5010.04, 5010.04, 5010.04, 5010.04, 5010.04, 
5010.04, 5010.04, 5010.04, 5010.04, 5010.04, 5010.04, 5010.04, 
5010.04, 5010.04, 5010.04, 5010.04, 5010.04, 5010.04, 5010.04, 
5010.04, 5010.04, 5010.04, 5010.04, 5010.04, 5010.04, 5010.04, 
5010.04, 5010.04, 5010.04, 5010.04, 5010.04, 5010.04, 5010.04, 
5010.04, 5010.04, 5010.04, 5010.04, 5010.04, 5010.04, 5010.04, 
5010.04, 5010.04, 5010.04, 5010.04, 5010.04, 5010.04, 5010.04, 
5010.04, 5010.04, 5010.04, 5010.04, 5010.04, 5010.04, 5010.04, 
5010.04, 5010.04, 5010.04, 5010.04, 5010.04, 5010.04, 5010.04, 
5010.04, 5010.04, 5010.04, 5010.04, 5010.04, 5010.04, 5011.03, 
5011.03, 5011.03, 5011.03, 5011.03, 5011.03, 5011.03, 5011.03, 
5011.03, 5011.03, 5011.03, 5011.03, 5011.07, 5011.07, 5011.07, 
5011.07, 5011.07, 5011.07, 5011.07, 5011.07, 5011.07, 5011.07, 
5011.07, 5011.07, 5011.07, 5011.07, 5011.07, 5011.07, 5011.07, 
5011.07, 5011.07, 5011.07, 5011.07, 5011.07, 5011.07, 5011.07, 
5011.07, 5011.07, 5011.07, 5011.07, 5011.07, 5011.07, 5011.07, 
5017.06, 5025.22, 5025.22, 5025.22, 5025.22, 5025.22, 5025.22, 
5025.22, 5025.22, 5025.22, 5025.22, 5025.22, 5025.22, 5025.22, 
5025.22, 5025.22, 5025.22, 5025.22, 5025.22, 5025.22, 5025.22, 
5025.22, 5025.22, 5025.22, 5025.22, 5025.22, 5025.22, 5025.22, 
5025.22, 5025.22, 5025.22, 5025.26, 5025.26, 5025.26, 5025.26, 
5025.26, 5025.26, 5025.26, 5025.26, 5025.26, 5025.26, 5025.26, 
5025.26, 5025.26, 5025.26, 5025.26, 5025.26, 5025.26, 5025.26, 
5025.26, 5025.26, 5025.26, 5025.26, 5025.26, 5025.26, 5025.26, 
5025.26, 5025.26, 5025.26, 5025.26, 5025.26, 5025.26, 5025.26, 
5025.26, 5025.26, 5025.26, 5025.26, 5025.26, 5025.26, 5025.26, 
5025.26, 5032.24, 5032.24, 5032.24, 5032.24, 5032.24, 5032.24, 
5032.24, 5032.24, 5032.24, 5032.24, 5032.24, 5032.24, 5032.24, 
5032.24, 5032.24, 5032.24, 5032.24, 5032.24, 5032.24, 5032.24, 
5032.24, 5032.24, 5032.24, 5032.24, 5032.24, 5032.24, 5032.24, 
5032.24, 5032.24, 5032.24, 5032.24, 5032.24, 5032.24, 5032.24, 
5032.24, 5032.24, 5032.24, 5032.24, 5032.24, 5032.24, 5032.24, 
5032.24, 5032.24, 5032.24, 5032.24, 5032.24, 5032.24, 5032.24, 
5032.24, 5032.24, 5032.24, 5032.24, 5032.24, 5032.24, 5032.24, 
5032.24, 5032.24, 5032.24, 5032.24, 5032.24, 5032.24, 5032.24, 
5032.24, 5032.24, 5032.24, 5032.24, 5032.24, 5032.24, 5032.24, 
5032.24, 5032.24, 5032.24, 5032.24, 5032.24, 5032.24, 5032.24, 
5032.24, 5032.24, 5032.24, 5032.24, 5038.04, 5038.04, 5038.04, 
5038.04, 5038.04, 5038.04, 5038.04, 5038.04, 5038.04, 5038.04, 
5038.04, 5038.04, 5038.04, 5038.04, 5038.04, 5038.04, 5038.04, 
5038.04, 5038.04, 5038.04, 5039.03, 5039.03, 5039.03, 5039.03, 
5039.03, 5039.03, 5039.03, 5039.03, 5039.03, 5039.03, 5039.03, 
5039.03, 5039.03, 5039.03, 5039.03, 5039.03, 5039.03, 5039.03, 
5039.03, 5039.07, 5045, 5045, 5053.26, 5066.04, 5067.07, 5067.07, 
5067.07, 5067.07, 5067.07, 5067.07, 5067.07, 5067.07, 5067.07, 
5067.07, 5067.07, 5067.07, 5067.07, 5067.07, 5067.07, 5067.07, 
5067.07, 5067.07, 5067.07, 5067.07, 5067.07, 5073.06, 5073.06, 
5074.16, 5074.16, 5074.16, 5074.16, 5074.16, 5074.16, 5074.16, 
5074.16, 5074.16, 5074.16, 5074.16, 5074.16, 5088.11, 5094.04, 
5094.04, 5094.04, 5101.06, 5101.06, 5101.06, 5101.06, 5101.06, 
5101.06, 5101.06, 5101.06, 5101.06, 5101.06, 5101.06, 5101.06, 
5101.06, 5101.06, 5101.06, 5101.06, 5101.06, 5101.06, 5101.06, 
5101.06, 5101.06, 5101.06, 5101.06, 5101.06, 5101.06, 5101.06, 
5101.06, 5101.06, 5101.06, 5101.06, 5101.06, 5101.06, 5116.24, 
5116.24, 5116.24, 5116.24, 5116.24, 5116.24, 5116.24, 5116.24
), SiteVisits = c("IC1", "RGD1", "RGD1", "RGD1", "RGD1", "RGU1", 
"ORS1", "WC1", "WC2", "WC3", "WC2", "WC3", "IC3", "RGD1", "RGU1", 
"ORS1", "WC1", "WC2", "WC3", "RGD1", "RGU1", "WC2", "WC3", "WC3", 
"RGU1", "ORS1", "WC1", "WC2", "WC3", "RGU1", "ORS1", "WC1", "WC2", 
"WC3", "RGU1", "ORS1", "WC1", "WC2", "WC3", "RGD1", "RGU1", "ORS1", 
"WC1", "RGD1", "RGD1", "RGD1", "RGD1", "RGD1", "IC3", "IC1", 
"RGD1", "RGD1", "RGU1", "ORS1", "WC1", "WC2", "RGU1", "ORS1", 
"WC1", "RGU1", "ORS1", "WC1", "WC2", "WC3", "IC3", "IC1", "RGD1", 
"RGU1", "ORS1", "WC1", "WC2", "WC3", "RGD1", "WC1", "WC2", "WC3", 
"WC3", "RGD1", "RGU1", "WC1", "WC2", "WC3", "RGD1", "IC3", "IC2", 
"IC1", "RGD1", "RGU1", "WC1", "WC2", "WC3", "WC3", "RGD1", "RGU1", 
"WC1", "WC2", "WC3", "IC3", "IC2", "IC1", "RGD1", "IC3", "IC2", 
"IC1", "RGD1", "IC3", "IC2", "IC1", "RGD1", "IC3", "IC2", "IC1", 
"RGD1", "RGD1", "RGD1", "RGD1", "IC2", "IC1", "IC3", "IC2", "IC1", 
"IC3", "IC2", "IC1", "IC3", "IC2", "IC1", "IC1", "IC3", "IC2", 
"IC1", "IC2", "IC1", "IC3", "IC2", "IC1", "IC2", "IC3", "IC2", 
"IC1", "IC1", "IC1", "IC3", "IC1", "IC1", "IC3", "IC1", "IC1", 
"IC1", "RGD1", "RGD1", "IC3", "RGD1", "IC3", "IC2", "IC2", "IC1", 
"IC1", "IC1", "IC1", "IC3", "IC1", "IC3", "IC1", "IC3", "IC1", 
"IC3", "IC1", "IC1", "IC3", "IC1", "IC3", "IC2", "IC1", "IC3", 
"IC2", "IC1", "IC3", "IC2", "IC1", "IC3", "IC2", "IC1", "RGD1", 
"IC3", "IC2", "IC1", "RGD1", "IC3", "IC2", "IC1", "RGD1", "IC2", 
"IC1", "RGD1", "IC1", "IC1", "RGD1", "IC1", "IC1", "IC3", "IC2", 
"IC1", "IC3", "IC1", "IC3", "IC2", "IC1", "RGD1", "RGD1", "RGD1", 
"RGD1", "RGD1", "IC3", "IC2", "IC1", "RGD1", "RGD1", "IC1", "RGD1", 
"RGD1", "RGD1", "RGD1", "RGD1", "IC2", "RGD1", "IC1", "IC1", 
"RGD1", "IC3", "IC2", "IC1", "IC3", "IC2", "IC1", "IC3", "IC2", 
"IC1", "IC3", "IC2", "IC1", "IC3", "IC2", "IC1", "IC3", "IC2", 
"IC1", "IC3", "IC2", "IC1", "IC3", "IC2", "IC3", "IC2", "IC3", 
"IC2", "IC1", "IC3", "IC2", "IC1", "IC3", "IC2", "IC3", "IC2", 
"IC1", "IC3", "IC2", "IC1", "IC3", "IC2", "IC1", "IC3", "IC2", 
"IC1", "IC1", "IC1", "IC1", "IC3", "IC2", "IC1", "IC1", "IC1", 
"IC1", "IC1", "IC2", "IC1", "IC1", "IC2", "IC1", "IC2", "IC1", 
"IC1", "IC3", "IC2", "IC1", "IC2", "IC1", "IC3", "IC2", "RGD1", 
"RGD1", "RGD1", "RGD1", "RGD1", "RGD1", "RGD1", "RGD1", "IC1", 
"RGD1", "IC2", "IC1", "RGD1", "RGD1", "RGD1", "IC3", "IC1", "RGD1", 
"IC3", "IC2", "IC1", "IC3", "IC2", "IC1", "IC3", "IC2", "IC1", 
"RGD1", "IC3", "RGD1", "IC3", "RGD1", "IC3", "IC2", "RGD1", "IC3", 
"IC2", "RGD1", "RGD1", "IC2", "RGD1", "RGD1", "RGD1", "RGD1", 
"IC3", "IC2", "IC1", "RGD1", "RGD1", "IC2", "IC1", "RGD1", "RGD1", 
"IC1", "IC3", "IC2", "IC1", "RGD1", "RGD1", "IC3", "IC2", "IC1", 
"RGD1", "IC3", "IC2", "IC1", "RGD1", "IC3", "IC2", "IC1", "IC3", 
"IC2", "IC1", "RGD1", "IC3", "IC2", "IC1", "RGD1", "RGD1", "RGD1", 
"RGD1", "RGD1", "RGD1", "RGD1", "RGD1", "RGD1", "RGD1", "RGD1", 
"RGD1", "RGD1", "RGD1", "RGD1", "RGD1", "RGD1", "RGD1", "RGD1", 
"RGU1", "ORS1", "RGD1", "RGD1", "RGD1", "RGD1", "RGD1", "RGD1", 
"RGD1", "RGD1", "IC2", "IC1", "RGD1", "IC2", "IC1", "IC2", "IC1", 
"RGD1", "RGD1", "RGD1", "RGD1", "IC1", "IC2", "IC1", "RGD1", 
"IC2", "IC3", "IC1", "IC3", "IC1", "RGD1", "IC2", "IC1", "RGD1", 
"IC3", "IC2", "IC1", "RGD1", "IC3", "IC3", "IC3", "IC3", "IC2", 
"IC3", "IC2", "IC3", "IC2", "IC2", "IC1", "RGD1", "RGD1", "RGD1", 
"RGD1", "RGU1", "ORS1", "RGU1", "ORS1", "WC1", "WC2", "GL1", 
"WC3", "RGD1", "IC1", "IC1", "IC1", "IC3", "IC2", "IC3", "IC2", 
"IC1", "IC3", "IC2", "IC1", "IC3", "IC2", "IC1", "RGD1", "RGD1", 
"RGD1", "RGD1", "RGD1", "RGU1", "ORS1", "WC1", "WC2", "WC3", 
"RGU1", "ORS1", "WC1", "WC2", "WC3", "WC1", "WC2", "WC3", "WC1", 
"WC2", "WC3", "IC2", "IC1", "RGD1", "IC3", "IC2", "IC1", "IC3", 
"IC2")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-500L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you mean by an incidence table but we can do a lot of this at once with `dplyr`, `tidyr` and `magrittr`

```
x$count <- 1
x2 <- split(x, x$Species)
x2 <- lapply(x2, function(x){split(x,x$Week)})
x3 <- lapply(x2, function(x){lapply(X=x, function(y){
  y <- y %>% spread(key = "SiteVisits",
                    value = "count",
                    fill =0) %>%
    select(-Species, -Week) %>% as.data.frame()
  rownames(y) <- y$TagID
  y <- y[,-1]
  y <- graph_from_incidence_matrix(y)
  return(y)
})})
```

`x3` will be a list structure where the final elements are the returned values of `graph_from_incidence_matrix`

Comment: Partially, you did create the correct form of incidence table, but the second part is the hard part (the network build) Let me see if I can find a way to work that in.  Unfortunately, I think the split at species and week is necessary to be able to create a single network for each species for each week.

Comment: the `pivot_wider` function was a bit overkill. Using two `lapply` functions we can make the incidence tables and the graph for each combination.

Comment: perfect, and a quick `x4 <- unlist(x3)` creates the same structure as beaches!  Thanks, I'll need to spend some time reviewing those lapply statements, but this seems to be excellent.

Comment: The starting value to `y` is essentially equivalent to calling `x2[[Species]][[Week]]`. This should help understanding the most internal function call. I could never find the beaches dataset, but hopefully this is enough to satisfy your question. Cheers!